# Connection between Android applicaton and remote MS SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server, json, web-services

I have a project about **pedesterian mobility analysis**. First I need collect walk pattern from students in the university campus. In order to collect GPS data, I developed android application. Now my application get longitude and latitude ever 30 second. Also I can get IMEI of the telephone and timestamp.

Now I need to store longitude, latitude, IMEI and timestamp to remote SQL server. In the university there is a server computer and it have MS SQL server. I must store the tracking datas to that server.

There is a lot of tutorial in the internet about RESTFul web services, JSON objects etc. but I can not understand exactly how to set up communications between **Android application and remote SQL server**? What kind of data flow between them?

I am a newbie about these technologies, please help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need is, a `ServerSide` language like `php` or even an script for serverside.so, after that, you should create an `Api` which says, receive the requests and then store it on `Mysql`.

there is a good tutorial about these things and all of it needs `php` knowledge:

http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/12924/android-tutorial-using-remote-databases-php-and-mysql-part-1/

especially, part4

http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/13130/android-mysql-register-and-login-php-scripts/

you can learn a lot about these things with above tutorial.